# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online device registration in Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dynamics-crm-online

We have a live website which runs on a VM. We are in process of moving it to Azure Website.

Our website is integrated to CRM Online, for integration we need to provide device id and device password and it is working fine on our live website.

But now in Azure Website, I can't run the deviceregistration.exe to generate device id and device password.

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading these articles:

http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/authenticating-using-live-id/
http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/authenticating-using-live-id-part-2/
http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/authenticating-using-live-id-part-3/

But I suggest (if it's possible) to wait that your CRM online instance will be migrated to Office 365 authentication.